# Efficiency with repetitive code - For loops with variable names

Tags: r

Consider the following dataframe in R,

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:7, Group = c(rep(1,2), rep(2, 3), rep(3,2)), Year = c(rep(2011, 4), rep(2012, 3)), X = rnorm(7))
```

I am working in base R, and would like to achieve the following task in a more efficient way.

```
 Group1 <- df[df$Group == 1,]
 Group2 <- df[df$Group == 2,]
 Group3 <- df[df$Group == 3,]
```

Here I am producing three separate dataframes by group, and giving the variable names a systematic naming scheme. This code is repetitive, and I would be looking to do this a better way (usually I have many more "groups", and so these ugly repetitive lines of code are taking up much space).

For my own learning, I would also love to see an example of this working a for loop, even though I'm sure there are better ways - something along the lines of:

```
for (i in 1:3){
Groupi <- df[df$Group == i,] }
```

Though this is obviously incorrect, hopefully you can see the intuition.

Any examples of more efficient working would be appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: See `help(split)`

Comment: In case the help doc confuses `split(df, df$Group)`. Also to help with repeated numbers, the group vector could've been created with `rep(1:3, c(2,3,2))`

Comment: Thankyou Rich, and also thankyou Pierre for the follow up - however, I still believe the systematic variable naming is an important part of the solution which I am looking for, however I was not familiar with split and I will think to use this in future, thankyou.

Comment: Your loop will work if you first define `Group <- list()` then use `Group[[i]] <- df[df$Group == i, ]`. And in other news, where are your terminal commas for the subset?

Comment: K how about `split(df, paste0("Group", df$Group))`.  Check the list names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better served with `split` as described in comments. However you can achieve what you're after with a loop using `assign`.

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste0("Group", i), df[df$Group==i,])
}
```

Also, careful with your indexing, you will need a comma to indicate "all columns".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation on @Rupert 's answer, one which automatically pulls the levels from the column:

```
makeGroupVars <- function(baseName,df,column){
  levs <- levels(as.factor(column))
  for(lev in levs){
      assign(paste0(baseName,lev),df[column == lev,],envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
  NULL
  }
```

For example, the call `makeGroupVars("Group",df, df$Group)` will create three variables `"Group1", "Group2", "Group3"` in the expected way. Furthermore, a call like `makeGroupVars("specie_",iris,iris$Species)` (where `iris` is a built-in example dataframe) will be able to create variables such as `specie_setosa`.

Having done all this, I suspect that the simple use of `split` is probably the best choice. Do you really need a cluttered namespace?